# Implement Icon morph animation in Javascript/CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, material-design, css-shapes

See this video

[image: http://materialdesign.qiniudn.com/videos/animation-delightfulDetails-statusChange-example_large_xhdpi.webm]

(HD video [here](http://materialdesign.qiniudn.com/videos/animation-delightfulDetails-statusChange-example_large_xhdpi.webm))

I was wondering whether there is an easier way to implement this in Javascript/CSS.

I know that there is some CSS3 attributes like `transition`, `animation`, `transform` and so on, but as I know, **none of these attributes can transform one icon into another and provide delicate effect like the top-left and top-right ones in the video above**.

Does anyone have ideas about what may be a good solution to implement this?

Comment: The answer to your question is **YES**, all of that is possible. SVG maybe better for the top right.

Comment: Of course it is possible. JavaScript is turing complete which means it can output *anything* other programs output.

Comment: @odedta If any demo or library could be provided, it will be much more helpful..

Comment: @hanfeisun, You can see an example at the answer below, here: http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/5Bz8g/63/. There's animate.css: https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/ - basically there are a lot of libraries that contain partials of what you're looking for, I don't know of a jQuery plugin that creates a whole solution for this, just look a specific thing on google.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image]

Right, I have come up with a similar look to show that this sort of thing is possible via **CSS only**. You will notice some differences, some of which maybe the way I coded this but you get the point.

So here it is!

**Note:** Stackoverflow's code snippets don't like some `CSS` properties and will not run them. This will be best viewed on [**Codepen here**](http://codepen.io/Ruddy/pen/dovqPE/).

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700);
 body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  background: #222;
}
.grid {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.box {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.box:nth-child(1) {
  background: #01FF70;
}
.box:nth-child(2) {
  background: #FFDC00;
}
.box:nth-child(3) {
  background: #0074D9;
}
.box:nth-child(4) {
  background: #FF4136;
  line-height: 300px;
}
/* Ham Burger */

.hamBurger {
  width: 110px;
  height: 16px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  animation: spin 5s infinite;
}
.hamBurger:before,
.hamBurger:after {
  content: "";
  width: 110px;
  height: 16px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
.hamBurger:before {
  top: -42px;
  animation: translateBefore 5s infinite;
}
.hamBurger:after {
  bottom: -42px;
  animation: translateAfter 5s infinite;
}
@keyframes translateBefore {
  20% {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    width: 60px;
    left: 52px;
    top: -24px;
  }
  40% {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    width: 60px;
    left: 52px;
    top: -24px;
  }
  60% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    width: 110px;
    left: 0;
    top: -42px;
  }
}
@keyframes translateAfter {
  20% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    width: 60px;
    left: 52px;
    bottom: -24px;
  }
  40% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    width: 60px;
    left: 52px;
    bottom: -24px;
  }
  60% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    width: 110px;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -42px;
  }
}
@keyframes spin {
  20% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  40% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  60% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
/* End of Ham Burger */

/* Refresh */

.refresh {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 16px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #fff;
  border-left-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  animation: refreshSpin 1s infinite linear;
}
.refresh:before {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 30px solid #fff;
  border-top: 30px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: -16px;
  left: 80%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
@keyframes refreshSpin {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(315deg);
  }
}
/* End of Refresh */

/* Numbers */

.plus,
.num1,
.num2 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 100px;
  color: #fff;
}
.plus {
  animation: plusSpin 5s infinite;
  margin-left: 30%;
}
.num1 {
  position: relative;
  animation: num1Effect 5s infinite;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.num2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: #FF4136;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  animation: num2Effect 5s infinite;
}
@keyframes num2Effect {
  30% {
    clip-path: polygon(100% 100%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  }
  70% {
    clip-path: polygon(100% 100%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  }
}
@keyframes num1Effect {
  30% {
    padding-left: 0px;
  }
  70% {
    padding-left: 0px;
  }
}
@keyframes plusSpin {
  20% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  70% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  90% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
/* End of Numbers */

/* Icons */

.icons {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 27%;
  left: 27%;
  animation: spinIcon 5s infinite;
}
.icons:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0px;
  background: #FFDC00;
  margin: 0 auto;
  animation: spinIconMiddle 5s infinite;
}
@keyframes spinIconMiddle {
  33% {
    width: 0;
  }
  66% {
    width: 30px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0px;
  }
}
@keyframes spinIcon {
  33% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  66% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(270deg);
  }
}
/* End of Icons */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="hamBurger"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="icons"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="refresh"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="plus">+</div>
    <div class="num1">
      <div class="num2">2</div>1
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

If there are any questions please asked.

---

**Further notes:**

- I couldn't think of a good way to create the triangle in the top
  right without using SVG. So I left that part out.
- This is using `clip-path`, this is not very well support as of yet. see more [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path).
- The script added is to make this prefix free.
- Created in Chrome, therefore it is best viewed in Chrome. This is nowhere near perfect, it is just to prove this can be done.

Comment: Thanks, Ruddy! Is it sure for these four parts of animation to be synchronized if CSS3 animation is used?

Comment: @hanfeisun Of course you can, its just a matter of timing.

Answer (score 4):

Your designs are all fully possible with css. All of which will require slightly different approaches (as you can see in my demo), but all are fully possible.

For example,

- the top left part can be made with two pseudo elements, and rotated and borders altered on hover.
- the top right can be created with a border-hack, altering the borders and width on hover
- the bottom left can be created as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30049464/3436942)
- the bottom right can be created using multiple pseudo elements and a change in `data-attr`. (if, for example, you then wanted +3, you would have to alter the `data-start` attr through javascript)

```css
img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.one {
  background: lightgreen;
}
*:before,
*:after,
a {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: all 0.6s;
}
.one:before {
  height: 40px;
  width: 60px;
  border: 10px solid white;
  border-left: 0px solid white;
  border-right: 0px solid white;
}
.one:after {
  height: 10px;
  width: 60px;
  background: white;
}
.one:hover:before {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(135deg);
  border-bottom: 10px solid white;
  border-right: 10px solid white;
  border-top: 0px solid white;
  width: 40px;
}
.one:hover:after {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
}
.two {
  background: orange;
}
.three {
  background: steelblue;
}
.four {
  background: tomato;
}
.two:before {
  width: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid white;
  border-top: 30px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
}
.two:hover:before {
  border: 0px solid transparent;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: white;
}
.four:before {
  content: attr(data-start);
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  opacity: 1;
}
.four:after {
  content: attr(data-end);
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  opacity: 0;
}
.four:hover:before {
  opacity: 0;
}
.four:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div><br/>
<div class="three"><a href="https://stackoverflow.com/a/30049464/3436942">See here</a>
</div>
<div class="four" data-start="+1" data-end="+2"></div>
```

Comment: i think you should remove the link from snippet and put it in the answer itself! Tha rotating arrow answer will not open inside the snippet. .

Answer (score -1):

You can always try some css filters combined with some transitions
No need for javascript. But you could use javascript to attach and remove classes so you can have different animations in different situations.

```css
.showbox {
    float: left;
    margin: 4em 1em;
    width: 100px;
    height: 60px;
    border: 2px solid green;
    background-color: #fff;
    line-height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    
    -webkit-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  }
  .showbox.slideright:hover {
    -webkit-transform: translate(3em,0) rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: translate(3em,0) rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: translate(3em,0) rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: translate(3em,0) rotate(360deg);
    transform: translate(3em,0) rotate(360deg);
  }
```

```html
<div class="showbox slideright">box 1</div>
```

Comment: I don't really feel like this is a good answer at all. The question is flawed anyways. The answer is just a plain **yes**.

Comment: A plain yes does not point him in the right direction. Notice how simple the answer is. Sometimes all you need is a pointer to know if something is possible.

Comment: As far as the question goes the OP did not ask how can I make this in JS/ CSS it says can this be made in JS/CSS. The question should probably be closed as too broad. The question overall could be made into something worthy of being on SO and could be an interesting one that I would like to take part in. But we will see what the OP does with it.

Comment: I know that there is some CSS3 attributes like transition, animation, transform and so on, but as I know, **none of these attributes can transform one icon into another and provide delicate effect like the top-left and top-right ones in the video I posted.**
@Ruddy

Comment: You can still do that with css transforms. Just have 3 divs as the bars, then on a mouseover have them follow the animation sequence to form into an arrow. You can also make timed animations. You have not shown any code or effort, you expect me to give you copy paste code?