# CSS Circular Arrow

Tags: html, css

I tried my best to create this using CSS https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMrY5.jpg the last thing I need is the circular arrow, but I cant seem to make it properly. Can anyone give me some pointers on how to create the arrow circle like in the photo. Anything helps, cheers.

```css
.container .row {text-align:center; position:relative;}
.center {
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:#1f497d;
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  border-width:3px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#ededed;
  border-radius:7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888888;
}

.left {
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:#1f497d;
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  border-width:3px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#ededed;
  border-radius:7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888888;
}

.right {
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:#1f497d;
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  border-width:3px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#ededed;
  border-radius:7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888888;
  margin-left:-35px;
}

.circle {
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:#006850;
  width:85px;
  height:85px;
  border-width:3px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#fefefe;
  border-radius:50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888888;
  margin-bottom:-15px;
}

.invisible {
  visibility:hidden;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:#1f497d;
  width:130px;
  height:65px;
  border-width:3px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#d6d6d6;
  border-radius:7px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888888;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="center"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="margin-top:-15px;">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="invisible"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="margin-top:-15px;">
    <div class="invisible"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="invisible"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="margin-top:-15px;">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="invisible"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="center"></div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30049084/how-can-i-create-a-round-arrow-with-only-html-and-css/

Comment: you can use this it's not perfect but it's pretty close https://jsfiddle.net/suunyz3e/1465/