# Draw a circular arrow with rounded ends in CSS

Tags: css, geometry

How can I draw a circular arrow with rounded ends in CSS?
Inside the circular arrow some dynamic text will be placed, but the issue is to draw the arrow.
Something like this:

[image]

Till now the only idea that came up was drawing a circle with the border but I'm sure I'm in the wrong direction with this.

```
.center-circle {
    width: 220px;
    height: 220px;
    display: flex;
    border: solid #C60C30 8px;
    border-radius: 110px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: You can also try svg, and use in css. https://www.svgrepo.com/svg/50/circular-arrow

Comment: You may find what you want [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30049084/how-can-i-create-a-round-arrow-with-only-html-and-css)

Comment: Give width and height in percentage, relative to parent container.

Answer (score 0):

I found pieces of code on the internet and changed according to your example.

- You can look for something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30049084/how-can-i-create-a-round-arrow-with-only-html-and-css)

```css
.arrow {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 6px solid #C60A30;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(237deg); 
}
.arrow:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -6px;
  margin: auto;
}
.arrow:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 20px solid #C60A30;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 106px;
  right: -20px;
  transform: rotate(356deg); 
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow"></div>
```

ps: You can also try svg, and use in css or fontawesome.

```css
img{
  transform: rotate(103deg);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/50/circular-arrow.svg" alt="">
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  <body class="geometry">
    <div class="arrow-round"></div>
  </body>
```

CSS

```
.arrow-round {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  border: 25px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-right-color: transparent;
}

.arrow-round::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;

  border: 50px solid #ffffff;
  top: -20px; 
  left: 69px;
  border-bottom-color: red;
  border-top-width: 0;
  border-right-width: 0;
  border-left-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).